# Rotating around an object with a given offset

Tags: c++, math, sfml

I'm attempting to create an effect where two projectiles will come out a given entity at a given offset to the player. A quick implementation was this;

```
sf::Vector2f offset = m_owner->GetSprite().getPosition();

offset.y -= 5;
createProjectile(offset, m_owner->GetSprite().getRotation());
offset.y += 10;
createProjectile(offset, m_owner->GetSprite().getRotation());
```

This worked perfectly fine if your entity only wanted to fire across the .x axis, but as soon as you rotated the player it broke as the offset was not going off the players current rotation.

I'm tried many implementation of this but none have seemed to work and as I'm shockingly bad at math, I cannot work it out myself.

```
void Weapon::createProjectile(const sf::Vector2f& position, float angle)
{
        m_owner->_state->addEntity(new Projectile(m_owner, position, angle,*m_texture, m_velocity, m_damage));
}

Projectile::Projectile(Entity* emitter, const sf::Vector2f& position, float angle,
    const sf::Texture& image, int speed, int damage) :
    Entity(emitter->_state, true, entityName::entityBullet, speed)
{
        Load(_state->getApp()->gettextureManager().Get("Content/ball.png"));
    GetSprite().setRotation(angle);

        SetPosition(position.x,position.y);
        GetSprite().setScale(0.4f,0.4);
}
```

ANSWER:

```
float rad;
offset = m_owner->GetSprite().getPosition();

rad = math::to_rad(m_owner->GetSprite().getRotation());

offset.x += 5*sin(rad);
offset.y += -5*cos(rad);

createProjectile(offset,m_owner->GetSprite().getRotation());

offset = m_owner->GetSprite().getPosition();

offset.x += -5*sin(rad);
offset.y += 5*cos(rad);

createProjectile(offset,m_owner->GetSprite().getRotation());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math you need to study up on is trigonometry. It is very useful!

If your character is rotated `theta` radians from "straight up" going clockwise, your top
offset will be:

```
offset.x += 5*sin(theta);
offset.y += -5*cos(theta);
```

and the other will be

```
offset.x += -5*sin(theta);
offset.y += 5*cos(theta);
```

This is "circle math" (trigonometry) the 5 is the offset you speak of, also called the radius of the circle. A quick sanity check when doing this kind of math is to consider what will happen at 0 radians. Some quick facts of `sin` and `cos`:

```
sin(0) = 0
cos(0) = 1
sin'(0) = 1
cos'(0) = 0
```

(the second ones are derivatives: sin is initially increasing, cos is flat at the start. Check their graphs.) This and a bit more intuition is helpful for writing graphics code - if we consider the case when `theta = 0` we get back your original code. One exception: you are getting the second offset relative to the first offset: I'd avoid doing that and instead make two copies of `m_owner->GetSprite().getPosition();` or reset `offset` after creating the first projectile.

Comment: I clearly need spoon feeding this as even after your excellent explanation, its still not sinking in.

I believe the entities rotation was in deg's so I converted it into radians and then attempted to perform the code above.

`code(rad = math::to_rad(m_owner->GetSprite().getRotation());

offset.x = 5*sin(rad);

offset.y = -5*cos(rad);

createProjectile(offset,rad);) 
`

Also, the code you give appears to cancel out the orginal position, how do i then apply it back to the orginal one?

Comment: Did it work? Judging by your original code `createProjectile` should take the degrees version, shouldn't it? Perhaps put the code to `createProjectile` into your original question.

Comment: After double checking, createProjectile() takes the rotation in degree's as its then applied to the sprite which takes it in dedegree's.

So I was correct in converting it from deg's to rad's, I did something right for once!

Comment: Got it working! :) Change your `offset = ` to `offset +=` and it works! Will put working code in the question now, thanks very much.

Comment: Er yep, apologies :) That would be creating the projectiles around (0, 0).  I will update my answer.

Comment: Jacob, I'd rather not create another question for this issue. In this question I wanted them to be at either side of the ship, what i wanted something to rest at the back of the ship, which way around would the sin and cos be?

Comment: To get a 2D line that is at a 90 degree angle to another, swap `x` and `y` and make one of them negative (which you make negative depends on which of the two perpendicular lines you want.) Alternatively, add/subtract `M_PI/2.0` to/from `theta`.